# Get group by and distinct count of values using other field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index having document structure as below -

```
{
  "key": ["10", "20"],
  "keywords": [
    {
      'case': 1,
      'word': 'abc' 
    },
    {
      'case': 2,
      'word': 'def'
    },
    {
      'case': 1
      'word': abcd
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to apply filter on key=10 & get the count of distinct words by each case accros the documents. There are 20 disinct cases, so  this query will return is 20 buckets at max.

**Filter Condition:**
key = 10

## Expected result set

```
[
    {
      'case': 1,
      'value': 2
    },
    {
      'case': 2,
      'value': 1
    }
  ]
```

Equivalent SQL Query for this is -

```
select case, count(distinct words) as value 
from <table> where key = 10 and case in (1, 2, 3, 4) group by case;
```

Answer (score 1):

## First map the nested structure as nested datatype in ES index.

Mapping reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308817/elastic-search-mapping-for-nested-json-objects).

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "key": "123"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "keywords": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "keywords"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subjects": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "keywords.case.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "keywords.word.keyword",
                "precision_threshold": 4000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```